# Do $\infty$-categories make Grothendieck duality simpler?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

I've heard multiple times that *the main difficulty of Grothendieck duality is that triangulated categories don't 'glue well'*.

In my view, there are 3 parts in understanding Grothendieck duality:

1. We have to prove the existence of a right adjoint $f^!$ of $\mathsf{R}f_*$.
2. We have to be able to compute this adjoint. This means establishing relative / absolute purity results and computing the counit of the adjunction.
3. Proving a coherence result.

(I'll explain in detail what this all means afterwards, for those unfamiliar.) The first part was hard in *Residues and Duality* but is really simple today using Brown representability. The second part seems to have been recently simplified (vide Neeman's *Grothendieck duality made simple*), but not with homotopical tools. And the third part seems to be basically an open problem, as far as I know. (But I would love to be wrong!)

Well... now we have the machinery of stable $\infty$-categories, making $X\mapsto \mathsf{D}_{\text{qc}}(X)$ a sheaf and giving us a nice theory of descent. This seems the perfect solution to the problem described in the first paragraph of this question. **So, precisely, what points became easier?**

*Explanation of the parts above.* Point 1 seems fairly clear. The computation of the mysterious function $f^!$ is usually divided as follows: we prove that, in favorable cases, $f^!(-)\cong \mathsf{L}f^*(-)\otimes f^!\mathcal{O}_S$ (this is a relative purity result) and we compute $f^!\mathcal{O}_S$ (this is an absolute purity result). Then, the counit of the adjunction gives us a map
$$\hom(M,f^!N)\xrightarrow{\mathsf{R}f_*} \hom(\mathsf{R}f_*M,\mathsf{R}f_*f^!N)\xrightarrow{\hom(-,\varepsilon)} \hom(\mathsf{R}f_*M,N).$$
(A priori we should also describe the morphism going on the other way, but people are usually happy with just this one.) Finally, we have a lot of functors, and they should all satisfy the (sometimes) obvious coherence relations (i.e., commuting diagrams). A coherence result would prove that all diagrams that should commute, commute.

Comment: Just a guess: could it be that we’d like to construct $f^!$ first on some (etale) cover and then glue? If the the assignment $X \mapsto QCoh(X)$ formed a sheaf of categories then this would be a valid approach

Comment: Actually, you may be interested in the theory of ind-coherent sheaves developed by Gaitsgory/Rozenblyum. Part of the motivation there is to construct an exceptional inverse image functor for arbitrary morphisms

Comment: @leibnewtz well... $X\mapsto \mathsf{D}_{\text{qc}}(X)$ forms a sheaf of stable $\infty$-categories. So this approach should work. But this appears to only solve part 1, which is already *very* simple (ever since Neeman's 1996 paper introducing Brown representability on triangulated categories) and works perfectly fine on triangulated categories!

Comment: I took a look in Gaitsgory/Rozenblyum's work, and it seems very interesting indeed. I don't know if we gain anything in the context of schemes, though. We already have a functor $f^!$ for any separated map of finite-type. (Actually $\mathsf{R}f_*$ has a right adjoint in complete generality but, in some sense, this only gives the desired functor for proper $f$. So we define $f^!$ in general using a compactification.)

Comment: What kind of coherence result do you mean in (3)?

Comment: @DenisNardin some result similar to MacLane's coherence theorem, proving that all diagrams that should commute, commute. The preface to B. Conrad book "Grothendieck Duality and Base Change" explains exactly what I have in mind. This post is also in the same lines: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404072/does-the-language-of-fibred-categories-gives-the-commutativity-of-the-diagrams-i

Comment: @Gabriel If I understand correctly, it seems like the coherence conditions you are asking for just amount to the requirement that $X \mapsto D_{qc}(X)$ is functorial in $X$. In Gaitsgory/Rozenblyum they formulate the theory of ind-coherent sheaves as a functor out of the category of correspondences. This packages the six-functor formalism into a concise theory

Comment: @leibnewtz I surely don't understand well enough the book by Gaitsgory/Rozenblyum but it's not very clear to me that this approach simplifies the 3 parts. I mean... they spend most of the first book and even some of the second book to develop this theory. We can prove at least the first two parts with way less effort. (And I'm not sure that they prove part 2.)

Comment: @Gabriel Let me direct your attention to page $273$ where they explain how the six functor formalism can be encoded in the data of a single functor. One can perhaps prove each property/compatibility in the language of derived or $1$-categories in a more elementary way, but I think being able to do it all in one step in the language of infinity categories is an advantage of the theory.

Comment: @leibnewtz that seems indeed very interesting. Do you know if this approach gives the desired information for QCoh, instead of IndCoh? (Is QCoh a "subcategory" of IndCoh, in some sense?) Also, just to confirm, what they denote by QCoh is actually D_qc, isn't it?

Comment: @Gabriel I don't know most of the details, but my guess is that the formalism can be applied to any context in which one expects the six functors (see e.g. page $278$). In general, I don't think $QCoh$ is a subcategory of $IndCoh$, but there is a symmetric monoidal transformation of functors $QCoh \to IndCoh$. I believe this is an equivalence for nice enough (smooth?) schemes, as well as de Rham stacks. What they call $QCoh(X)$ may be thought of as the $DG$ enhancement of the derived category of quasicoherent sheaves on $X$